# How to select & change color button for different button group?

Tags: html, css, button

I am creating two button groups. whenever I click a button from second button group, already selected button from 1st group is getting deselected. i am able to select only one button both group. i want to select one button from each group. This is the code & I use :focus (css) for button.

**EDIT**

I need to use button type for bootsrap (btn-primary)

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.btn-group {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /*blue*/
  background-color: #2c75ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  /*green*/
  background-color: #85c995;
}

.btn:focus {
  /*green*/
  background-color: #85c995;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="width:30%">
    <div class="btn-group" id="group1" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="outline-color:red; " @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(11)">@Language.T35</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(12)">@Language.T36</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" btn btn-primary " @onclick="()=> UpdateTheChart(13)">@Language.T37</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="width:70%">
    <div class="btn-group" id="group2" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(21)">@Language.T138</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(22)">@Language.T38</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(23)">@Language.T39</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(24)">@Language.T40</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to apply `:focus` to multiple elements at the same time.

You'll need to manually add/remove a CSS class to the selected item in each group or change your code to use the more appropriate radio button group in this scenario.

For example (pseudo-code, may not work as-is):

```
// Get all the buttons and add a click handler to them
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-group .btn");
buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // do the UpdateChart stuff using some id property instead of inline onclick attribute
      UpdateTheChart(this.dataset.id);

      // find the button that has focus in the this button's group and remove the class
      this.parentElement.querySelector(".btn-focus").removeClass("btn-focus");

      // add the focus class to this button
      this.addClass("btn-focus");
   });
});
```

Note: for this to work you'll have to change your CSS to use the className instead of the :focus pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer

Unluckily, "button groups" for multiple/single selection doesn't exist, that's the job of `radio`s and `checkbox`es.

### The long one

As you want to select one option per group, you should be using `radio`s, as you can make groups (grouping by the `name` prop) and keep selected (`checked`) one option for each group.

Applying the solution:

You need to move your `@onclick` event to the `label` (as it's your new "button"), and hide the `radio`, so you keep the same UI.

Notice I place each `label` after their respective `radio` so we can select them with `input[type="radio"]:checked + label`, meaning: for the `label` immediately after a checked `radio`, apply that style.

E.g.:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  /*blue*/
  background-color: #2c75ff;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: fit-content;
}

label:hover,
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  /*green*/
  background-color: #85c995;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <input type="radio" name="groupA" id="T35" />
    <label for="T35" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(11)">@Languaje.T35</label>
    <input type="radio" name="groupA" id="T36" />
    <label for="T36" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(12)">@Languaje.T36</label>
    <input type="radio" name="groupA" id="T37" />
    <label for="T37" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(13)">@Languaje.T37</label>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <input type="radio" name="groupB" id="T138" />
    <label for="T138" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(21)">@Languaje.T138</label>
    <input type="radio" name="groupB" id="T38" />
    <label for="T38" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(22)">@Languaje.T38</label>
    <input type="radio" name="groupB" id="T39" />
    <label for="T39" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(23)">@Languaje.T39</label>
    <input type="radio" name="groupB" id="T40" />
    <label for="T40" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(21)">@Languaje.T40</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you edited telling that you need the `btn-primary` class, by adding it to the `label` it should be fine. Otherwise, we cannot keep selection/focus for more than one `button` at the same time.

Comment: Hey I tried this but doesn't work
the button change to radio button & the click also doesnt work only hover work. 
TQ

Comment: At the label I already add the btn-primary but it  change to radio button.

Comment: What do you mean by the "click" doesn't work, is it the selection, or the event `onclick`?

Comment: Im sorry my mistake, the button does click but doesnt change color once clicked.

Comment: Ok, maybe the selector we created has a lower specificity than the `btn-primary` one, is not the best practice, but try adding `!important` to see if it applies. Or add more specificity by hand, like `div.row > div.column > input[type="radio"]:checked + label`.